# Accessing the fields of a content via theme file in Drupal 8

Tags: entities

I have a content type called vanilla spice and it has various fields.
Afterward, I go ahead and create relevant content.

How can I display parts of that content type in my homepage?

In my themename.module I did the following:

```
function amarula_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $nid = 61;
    $node_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
    $node = $node_storage->load($nid);
    $variables['vanilla_node'] = $node->field_vanilla_heading->value;
}
```

In page--front.html.twig I tried to inspect the variable:

```
{{ kint(vanilla_node) }}
```

When I view the page, the variable shows as NULL.

How can I get the field values based on the node id?

Comment: `$nid = 38;
  $node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid);
  $variables['test'] = $node->field_name->value;` works for me. Is `themename.module` your actual file name? Where does that file live?

Comment: themename.module lives in the root directory inside the theme folder

Comment: @Prestosaurus your comment is actually useful. Would there be a different way of doing this? Maybe instantiating a class or so.

Comment: A theme file will have the file name themename.theme, not .module.